# Remove .clone() call when switching enum variants

Tags: rust

I have an enum, one variant of which has some data:

```rust
enum TaskState<S>
{
    NotSet,
    ToDo(S),
    Doing,
    Done
}
```

This is used to track tasks that some separate threads are responsible for carrying out.
When ready, one of them will query an instance of this enum, and if it's in its `ToDo(S)` state, the thread will take the `S` value and switch the enum's value to `Doing`.

My current code that does is as follows:

```rust
impl<S> TaskState<S>
{
    /// Take the spec off of ToDo and change the state to Doing.
    /// If this wasn't in ToDo, then return [None]
    fn take_todo(&mut self) -> Option<S> {
        if let TaskState::ToDo(specification) = self {
            // seems like an unnecessary clone??
            let specification = specification.clone();
            // let specification = std::mem::take(specification); // ????
            *self = TaskState::Doing;
            Some(specification)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

However, is there some way to `std::mem::take` the `S` from the enum? Thus it'll remove the `.clone()` call.

Commented out attempt above, but since that initializes an `S::default()` that doesn't feel like its correct?

Comment: What's wrong with `S::default()`? That's usually what you want, so if you have a reason you don't want that, add it to the question. You're overwriting it immediately anyway so as long as it doesn't do something unwanted on drop, it's fine.

Comment: I'm happy with S::default() if it is the more efficient solution vs. .clone(). Would it be? At least in my code the default() doesn't do too much computing.

Comment: If `clone` does a heap allocation and `default` doesn't, then `default` would likely be better. And since Rust is usually good at removing unused stack values, `default` is probably as good as any method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use `take` on `S`, you can instead use `replace` on your whole enum.

```rust
fn take_todo(&mut self) -> Option<S> {
    let temp_self = std::mem::replace(self, Self::Doing);
    if let Self::ToDo(specification) = temp_self {
        Some(specification)
    } else {
        *self = temp_self;
        None
    }
}
```

If you are okay with implementing `Default` for your enum, you can also use `take`.

```rust
impl<S> Default for TaskState<S> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::Doing
    }
}

impl<S> TaskState<S> {
    /// Take the spec off of ToDo and change the state to Doing.
    /// If this wasn't in ToDo, then return [None]
    fn take_todo(&mut self) -> Option<S> {
        let temp_self = std::mem::take(self);
        if let Self::ToDo(specification) = temp_self {
            Some(specification)
        } else {
            *self = temp_self;
            None
        }
    }
}
```

If you want something other than `Doing` to be default, you can assign it later. This is particularly useful if you have an enum variant specifically for invalid states, but you can also use whichever variant makes the most sense.

```rust
impl<S> Default for TaskState<S> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::NotSet
    }
}

impl<S> TaskState<S> {
    /// Take the spec off of ToDo and change the state to Doing.
    /// If this wasn't in ToDo, then return [None]
    fn take_todo(&mut self) -> Option<S> {
        let temp_self = std::mem::take(self);
        if let Self::ToDo(specification) = temp_self {
            *self = Self::Doing;
            Some(specification)
        } else {
            *self = temp_self;
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, the first snippet you have I think works very well for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be sure without seeing more of your code, but one way I've done state machines with stateful enums in Rust is to have a lifetime wrapped around each stateful enum variant and its data:

```
enum TaskState<'a, S> {
    NotSet,
    ToDo {
        spec: &'a S,
    },
    Doing,
    Done,
}
```

You should then be able to return a reference to spec without a clone by declaring a return lifetime that matches or exceeds `'a` on the input value.

I haven't tested it, but you may even be able to elide the lifetimes on the input/return once you have declared on the enum.

One other design comment: I normally use a mutable holder for the state enum, which is changed every loop through the state machine, rather than the enum value mutating itself (`*self = ...`). I guess your approach still works because enum variants have to have the same memory allocation, but I think self-mutation like this is a bit of an antipattern.

Comment: Yes, I should learn and play with more elided lifetimes, but my code is all inside a framework [Bevy] and I haven't quite got my head around what they allow and not allow. I'll keep your anti-pattern comment in mind, next time I'm working with state machines.